# Objects data removed when back pressed.singleton object having data permanently

Tags: android, object, singleton

I'm having a singleton class A with some variables like name,age whose object holding values all over app. But inside singleton class another normal class(nested) B defined. which is having address(for example). In another fragment/activity A class object holding value but B class value holding at first time but if back pressed or some scenario it became null. how to solve either by nested singleton class or any other way?

Comment: can you brief you question more ?

Comment: class A { string name,age; (SINGLETON) STATIC OBJECT<><>class B{ string address,phone; NORMAL OBJECT,getters,setters}} A-parent class B-nested inside class. A object.name has constant value as its static obj but B obj has value at starting but back pressed its became null.